# Spawning a process with {create_group=True} / set_pgid hangs when starting Docker

Tags: docker, haskell, process, process-group

Given a Linux system, in Haskell GHCi 8.8.3, I can run a Docker command with:

```
System.Process> withCreateProcess (shell "docker run -it alpine sh -c \"echo hello\""){create_group=False} $ \_ _ _ pid -> waitForProcess pid
hello
ExitSuccess
```

However, when I switch to `create_group=True` the process hangs. The effect of `create_group` is to call `set_pgid` with [`0` in the child](https://github.com/haskell/process/blob/c81932e8d993f7ab8034757c9a3da79e2fb235ad/cbits/runProcess.c#L176-L178), and [`pid` in the parent](https://github.com/haskell/process/blob/c81932e8d993f7ab8034757c9a3da79e2fb235ad/cbits/runProcess.c#L304-L306). Why does that change cause a hang? Is this a bug in Docker? A bug in System.Process? Or an unfortunate but necessary interaction?

Comment: It seems to be related to `-i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached`: with just `-t` instead of `-it`, the hang goes away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a bug in Haskell or a bug in Docker, but rather just the way that process groups work. Consider this C program:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    if(setpgid(0, 0)) {
        perror("setpgid");
        return 1;
    }
    execlp("docker", "docker", "run", "-it", "alpine", "echo", "hello", (char*)NULL);
    perror("execlp");
    return 1;
}
```

If you compile that and run `./a.out` directly from your interactive shell, it will print "hello" as you'd expect. This is unsurprising, since the shell will have already put it in its own process group, so its `setpgid` is a no-op. If you run it with an intermediary program that forks a child to run it (`sh -c ./a.out`, `\time ./a.out` - note the backslash, `strace ./a.out`, etc.), then the `setpgid` will put it in a new process group, and it will hang like it does in Haskell.

The reason for the hang is explained in ["Job Control Signals" in the glibc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html):

> Macro: *int* **SIGTTIN**
>
> A process cannot read from the user’s terminal while it is running as a background job. When any process in a background job tries to read from the terminal, all of the processes in the job are sent a `SIGTTIN` signal. The default action for this signal is to stop the process. For more information about how this interacts with the terminal driver, see [Access to the Terminal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Output-Modes.html#Output-Modes).
>
> Macro: *int* **SIGTTOU**
>
> This is similar to `SIGTTIN`, but is generated when a process in a background job attempts to write to the terminal or set its modes. Again, the default action is to stop the process. `SIGTTOU` is only generated for an attempt to write to the terminal if the `TOSTOP` output mode is set; see [Output Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Output-Modes.html#Output-Modes).

When you `docker run -it` something, Docker will attempt to read from stdin even if the command inside the container doesn't. Since you just created a new process group, and you didn't set it to be in the foreground, it counts as a background job. As such, Docker is getting stopped with `SIGTTIN`, which causes it to appear to hang.

Here's a list of options to fix this:

1. Redirect the process's standard input to somewhere other than the TTY
2. Use [`signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) or [`sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to make the process ignore the `SIGTTIN` signal
3. Use [`sigprocmask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) to block the process from receiving the `SIGTTIN` signal
4. Call `tcsetpgrp(0, getpid())` to make your new process group be the foreground process group (note: this is the most complicated, since it will itself cause `SIGTTOU`, so you'd have to ignore that signal at least temporarily anyway)

Options 2 and 3 will also only work if the program doesn't actually need stdin, which is the case with Docker. When `SIGTTIN` doesn't stop the process, reads from stdin will still fail with `EIO`, so if there's actually data you want to read, then you need to go with option 4 (and remember to set it back once the child exits).

If you have `TOSTOP` set (which is not the default), then you'd have to repeat the fix for `SIGTTOU` or for standard output and standard error (except for option 4, which wouldn't need to be repeated at all).

Comment: Thanks! For my purposes, closing the stdin makes the problem go away. There seems to be an issue that a new process group gets a stdin that hangs when read, and that's a problem.

Comment: @NeilMitchell The fact that `docker run -it` reads from stdin even when it doesn't need to was the piece that I was missing. With that piece of information, I now understand all of what was going on. I updated the answer with a longer explanation, and included some alternative solutions that will still work while still letting you use stdin, if you end up needing to do that.

Comment: that's really helpful! That does explain it all.